# "Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error

Tags: azure

Below is the code in my custom script extension

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows -OutFile $env:C:\temp\azcopy.zip
```

when I run my custom script extension , I am getting below error

"Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect this is because the URL you are trying to download from does not support anything but TLS 1.2. Set your protocol list to just Tls12.

Comment: Hi Sam, 

Still same the error, even after removing other protocols and retaining just Tls12

"message": "Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error \r\noccurred on a send.\r\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\\1.10.9\\Downloads\r\n\\0\\Final_v1.ps1:4 char:1\r\n+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows -Out ...\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt \r\n   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebReq